# Which Python modules are you using for network management and automation?

Tags: management

I was wondering if anyone has some favorite modules for doing things like SNMP, CLI screen scraping, netconf, etc...

Comment: I am closing this as I realize it is a poll.  However, I want to find some way to ask network specific automation and python questions as it relates directly to network management, without getting flagged that it should be in a different Exchange.

Comment: I guess I cannot close my own questions.

Comment: You should be able to delete your own question if you choose to do so.

Comment: Please don't delete it.  I'd vote to close it but apparently I don't have enough rep as I don't see an option.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I just started playing with [Trigger](https://readthedocs.org/projects/trigger/) and I have to say I've really enjoyed it.  It's quite a powerful network engineer toolkit and their documentation is awesome.  While we primarily have Cisco it does support other vendors such as Juniper and Brocade, they have a list of vendors in their [docs](https://trigger.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

Answer (score 6):

We've been using:

pysnmp - pretty obvious
Exscript - offers an enhanced "expect" type of experience.  Very nice.
MySQLdb - also self explanatory

Answer (score 5):

[ncclient](http://ncclient.grnet.gr/) is a python library for communicating via netconf. I've just started working with it.

Answer (score 5):

I use [Google Capirca](https://code.google.com/p/capirca/) for firewall / acl management.
It is simply a good rule generator, and the rule definition and generation are separated so you can even extend it to support any device you want. It does i.e. Linux iptables, Juniper SRX or Cisco ACLs out of the box.
The ACLs you write can be kept independent of the device type.

(the little geek brother of FW-1 rule compiler ;)

Answer (score 4):

Don't forget about:

- [Ciscoconfparse](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ciscoconfparse/)
- [Cisco CLI Automation](https://code.google.com/p/cisco-ios-cli-automation/)
- argparse (best module for parsing arguments)

Answer (score 3):

I use [Exscript](https://github.com/knipknap/exscript) for CLI screen scraping. It is a Python library and has also a minimalistic scripting language itself. The latter one is sufficient for most small tasks and doesn't require a lot of programming knowledge.

You can find some of my exscripts here:

https://github.com/verbosemode/exscripts

I've also written a grep-like tool based on ciscoconfparse and a templating tool (based on Jinja2) for text based configurations, which you can find on my github account (sorry, for the shameless self-promotion).